# Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse by rank decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, pseudoinverse

[The wikipedia page on Moore Penrose pseudo inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Rank_decomposition) shows a method using rank decomposition to compute the pseudo inverse :
$$A^+=C^+B^+=C^*(CC^*)^{-1}(B^*B)^{-1}B^* $$

But why $(CC^*)$ is inversible ? In particular I just realised that this is not true in some finite field, so the hypothesis that $\mathbb K$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ seems important.

Comment: I think many operations on matrices will become invalid( I seem to froget the examples) when the field is not $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.. leave alone finite fields

Comment: Because $C$ has full row-rank, $CC^*$ is invertible.  This is a trick that only works in fields of characteristic zero.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why is this not true in a finite field ?

Comment: Why should it be true?  I would say that the thing that "goes wrong" is that we no longer have a *norm* or *inner product* in the same sense as we would otherwise.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I would like to understand the proof of this result : why if $C$ has full row-rank then $CC^*$ is invertible in a field of characteristic zero. If you can explain that or give me a reference to the proof, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Theorem:** If $C$ has full row-rank in a field of characteristic zero, then $CC^*$ is invertible.

**Proof:** Note that for $x \in \Bbb F^{n} = \Bbb F^{n \times 1}$, we have
$$
CC^*x = 0 \implies\\
x^*CC^*x = 0 \implies\\
(C^*x)^*(C^*x) = 0 \overset{\text{char}(\Bbb F) = 0}{\implies}\\
C^*x \overset{\text{full row rank}}\implies\\ 
x = 0
$$
Since $C^*Cx = 0$ has only the trivial solution, $C^*C$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear for me now !